# Review Summarization Using Langchain and AzureOpenAI

Tags: python, langchain, large-language-model

Using Langhcain and Azure OpenAI, i would like to summarize the review based on the product's attributes. For example:

```
products = {'foo4':["cilt","kargo","orjinallik"],
            'foo3':["kurulum", "rüzgar geçirgenliği", "taşınabilirlik" , "güneş geçirgenliği"],
            'foo2':["şarj süresi","batarya kullanım süresi","emiş gücü"],
            'foo':["katlanabilirliği", "ağırlığı", "taşıma kapasitesi"]}
```

for each value element, i would like to get summarize. My code is as follows:

```
llm = AzureChatOpenAI(openai_api_key = openai.api_key,
                    deployment_name = 'openai.api_deployment_name',
                    openai_api_version = openai.api_version,
                    openai_api_base = openai.api_base,
                    openai_api_type = openai.api_type,
                    temperature=0,
                      )


PROMPT_TEMPLATE = ("Review and summarize user comments based on {content}. Summarize only comments on {content}.")

filename = "temp/foo.txt"
    
text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(
    chunk_size=10000,
    chunk_overlap=10,
)

loader = TextLoader(filename)
documents = loader.load()
docs = text_splitter.split_documents(documents)
embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings(model="text-embedding-ada-002",deployment="foo",openai_api_key=openai.api_key,openai_api_version=openai.api_version,openai_api_base=openai.api_base,openai_api_type=openai.api_type)

attributes = products['foo']

# db2 = Chroma.from_documents(docs, embeddings, persist_directory="./chroma_db_test")

db_disk = Chroma(persist_directory="./chroma_db_test", embedding_function=embeddings)

sonuc = {}
for attr in attributes:
    print("chunk is processing")
    chain = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(llm=llm, verbose=True,retriever=db_disk.as_retriever(search_kwargs={"k": 2}),)
    result = chain({"question": PROMPT_TEMPLATE.format(content=attr), "chat_history": []})
    sonuc[attr] = result['answer']

print(sonuc)
```

I have 7 documents loaded and regarding the "k" parameter in the retriever, I may get stuck chunk limit (for example if k is 4). If I create a separate document loader for each page content and loop over documents, I probably get a high LLM cost.

The question is, If the k parameter is set to 1 or 2, the retrieved reviews are reduced. If too large, stuck in the chunk limit. I do not want to miss any review in each document, how can I review all the docs in an LLM cost-friendly way based on the attributes?